# Conditional includes of header and implementation files containing functions with identical names

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include

When I try to compile the following 6 files all together, I get "multiple definition of `funcX(float, float)'" error.

If I remove "includeB.h" and "includeB.cpp" from the folder, then remaining 4 files are compiled. What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Assume my **common.h** file looks like this:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

// Uncomment needed Configuration Option
#define CONFIG  1 // Hardware Option 1
//#define CONFIG  2 // Hardware Option 2

#endif
```

and my **main.cpp** looks like this:

```
#include "common.h"

#if CONFIG == 1
  #include "includeA.h"
#else
  #include "includeB.h"
#endif

void main() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  float x;
  float a = 3.0;
  float b = 5.7;
  
  x = funcX(a, b);
}
```

My **includeA.h** file looks like this:

```
#ifndef INCLUDEA_H
#define INCLUDEA_H

float funcX(float a, float b);

#endif
```

and corresponding implementation file **includeA.cpp**:

```
#include "includeA.h"

float funcX(float a, float b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

My other header file **includeB.h** looks like:

```
#ifndef INCLUDEB_H
#define INCLUDEB_H

float funcX(float a, float b);

#endif
```

and corresponding to it the implementation file **includeB.cpp**:

```
#include "includeB.h"

float funcX(float a, float b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: You can't link both `includeA.cpp` and `includeB.cpp` into your program, since both define the same function. You need some logic when building to stop that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for noting that. My intention was that depending on the value of CONFIG  in the "common.h" file, I wanted to compile either "includeA h/cpp" or "includeB h/cpp" along with two filies: main.cpp, common.h. Appreciate if you can tell me how I can do that instead of removing unused two files during the compilation. Thank you

Comment: It's just not possible using only the compiler and its preprocessor. The compiler (and the preprocessor) only deals in a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (basically a single source file with all included header files). The compiler has no idea about any other translation units, and so can't be used to decide to link with a file or not. The linking is done as a separate step after compilation, and it has no idea about any possible preprocessor macros.

Comment: As a possible workaround you could add the `#if CONFIG == 1` in the other source files as well, for conditional compilation of the actual function definitions (implementations).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you very much for #if CONFIG == 1 option. I thought about this, but was hoping there could be better option for the problem. Thanks a lot for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two definitions for the same function (`funcX` here). Two solutions:

- set up your build system so that only one of `includeA.cpp` or `includeB.cpp` is linked to the executable.
- add an `#include "common.h"` in `includeA.cpp` and `includeB.cpp` and compile only one version of `funcX` depending on the value of `CONFIG`.

In both case, I'd suggest considering having only one `include.h` which would contains declarations independent of `CONFIG` and include `"common.h"` and then `includeA.h` or `includeB.h` depending on `CONFIG` for the dependent part.

Comment: thank you very much! It is too hard for me to figure out how to deploy your first option. But your second option is in my capability. Thanks a lot again!